# Why have I been able to access the Suggested Edits queues when I have <2K rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

Back when I had around 850 reputation on the Mathematics Stack Exchange, I got a review task in the Suggested Edits queue for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697178/evaluate-integral-int-infty-infty-gamma1ix-gamma1-ixdx) question of mine. The thing is, this was back when I had way less than 2K reputation - I actually had around 850 reputation at the time, so there wouldn't be any possible way for me to even review this in the first place, right?

This has also happened to me on Puzzling.SE 3 times, all on questions of mine.

So my question is, why is this happening? Even though all 4 of these edits have taken place on my questions, I had <2K rep at the time that I reviewed them and really don't think I should be able to access the Suggested Edits queue to review them.

---

Might be useful: "[Why was I given access to the "Suggested Edits" queue when I have not attained 2000 reputation yet?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35710/why-was-i-given-access-to-the-suggested-edits-review-queue-when-i-have-not-att)" by CrSb0001 (deleted post on Mathematics.SE Meta, -1 votes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always review edits on your own posts regardless of reputation.

Your vote is actually binding on such edits i.e. if you accept the edit then that's all it takes to apply it, and if you reject it then nobody else will be asked to review it to override that rejection.

After all it's your post so you should have the final say on what it contains most of the time.

Comment: Note RE "most of the time": diamond mods can override rejections (and accepts?) on suggested edits, even when done by the OP. It might have to be the most recent edit, but it's possible.